# Using pprint function to print first five elements

Tags: python, api, pyspark

I am trying to print the first five elements using the pprint function, but I cannot get it to work. I have tried the following code, but it gives me an error. How do you print just the first five elements instead of the first ten elements?

```
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
wordCounts.pprint(:5)
```

Comment: could you give us a minimal reproducible example? The data variable for example

Comment: It would be a lot of data if I had to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question does not provide simple data, I suppose the `wordCounts` variable is prepared through the following code.

```py
import pprint
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local', 'test')
pairs = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("d", 1), ("e", 1), ("a", 1), ("f", 1), ("c", 1)])
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

You can print the values in wordCounts by either of the followings:

```py
print(wordCounts.collect()[:5]) #Pick 5 elements
print(wordCounts.take(5)) #Pick 5 elements
print(sorted(wordCounts.collect())[:5]) #Sort the tuples, and pick the first 5 elements
print(sorted(wordCounts.collect(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)[:5]) #Sort by the second entry (i.e. count) in ascending order, and pick the first 5 elements
```

which produce

```py
[('a', 2), ('b', 5), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 1)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 5), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 1)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1)]
[('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 1), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

You are strongly advised to provide a minimal reproducible example next time.